# Single instances on google clound to group of instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have one instance on google clound, but the cpu usage is over 99% how can I scale or move that instance to an group I am using node js and mysql, this is possible?

Comment: Please move the case to serverfault because it's related with instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different options to create an instance group. you can use an unmanaged instance group [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#unmanaged_instance_groups) to use dissimilar instances that you can arbitrarily add and remove.

Or you can create an image template and use a managed instance group [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/#fundamentals) with identical instances, where you will be able to autoscale the number of instances.

But to give you a better answer, could you explain a little bit your application? Because if the only issue is the CPU usage, you can change the number of CPUs once the instance has stopped by with the edit button.